# Where does iCloud saves backups and documents? I can't find them

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, whatsapp.app, invisible-files

Please see the image below. I am using 5GB of iCloud space, it shows 966GB of backup of my old iphone in iCloud. The storage is the same the yellow in the horizontal bar. The problem is I cannot locate this on iCloud. I logged into icloud.com but it is not there. The same is the story for documents which is taking about 900MB space on iCloud but I cannot find it. The question how can I download them, where can I find them. I can delete it but I do not want to delete without backing it up first.

[image]

Adding a second screenshot, if I delete the whatsapp data, it gives me a message that it will be deleted from iDrive but the problem is I can't find it there hence can't back it up.
[image]

Comment: What version of macOS do you have? Is this Catalina?

Comment: @Ezekiel I am using Sierra 10.12.6, its' an old laptop.

Comment: If you still need help - we might want to split this into two questions. One for how third party apps / document deletion works and another on how to restore / access iOS / iPadOS backups

Answer (score 0):

You can delete backups from the screen you're looking at. Select the backup and click the [Delete] button. They won't appear anywhere else, except to restore a backup.

Documents refers to iCloud Drive (Other Documents) - but also to all other applications except for Photos and Backups. The entries you see for Whatsapp, etc. count towards this amount.

Comment: 1. When I select the iPhone back, it does not give me option to download. it says iphone back will be removed from iCloud and the action is not reversible.
2. My iCloud Drive, does not have any signicant data that I can see. There is no Whatsapp folder there which is taking all the space. Not sure how to find them.

Comment: 1. If you would like a local backup of your iPhone, you can use iTunes to complete a backup. Make sure to set a password, otherwise it won't include all information. You cannot download the backup from iCloud except to restore your phone.
2. For some applications like WhatsApp, that data is managed by the app. All you can do is delete it in iCloud. I don't use WhatsApp unfortunately.

Comment: I do realize that it may say there's an iCloud Drive folder for these apps, but it's not correct when it says that. If you have an iPhone, I'd recommend trying from there as it may be a slightly better interface.